# Position of the elements on maximized window

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a window with `WindowState="Maximized"` (which is also `AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None"` if it matters) and there is an `Image` element in the top left of the window.

But actual window.Left position = -8 and window.Top = -8.

Thus my image is cropped for that values.

I've made such a hack to avoid this:

```
image1.Margin = new Thickness(-this.Left - 1, -this.Top - 1, 0, 0);
```

but as you can see it looks really weird. What is the correct way to put the element in the *real* top left of the screen?

Comment: in what container is the image ? Canvas, Panel, Grid? and how is it positioned? absolute, relative?

Comment: It is in Grid. And it is positioned by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue.

Here's what I tried:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowState="Maximized">

    <Grid>
        <Image Source="E:\testImages\test.bmp" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

and with this, indeed, the window has a position of (-8, -8) which is normal as this is MS Windows's way to "hide" the windows's borders...

But this means that the window's content fits the screen perfectly, without being cropped, and my image is indeed fully displayed and is perfectly aligned on the left side of the screen and on top right beneath the titlebar, without further ado.

if I add your Hack, the image gets the given margin, and this puts it 8px right from the left side of the screen and 8xpx down from the titlebar.

so either I am missing some information or you issue does not lie there

---

***edit:***
I tried the sample project linked in commentary and found that the issue lies with "AllowsTransparency" being set to true on the window.

why it behaves like this, I have no idea...

Comment: It is an issue, even with your sample. Here is a dummy project that demonstrates it: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4486681/WpfApplication2.7z

Comment: interestingly enough, my debugging tells me the culprit is "AllowsTransparency = true"... as to "why", I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

You could set a style trigger that add margin when window is maximized

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowStyle="None" name="Window1">

<Grid>


<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/> // set your own values
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    </Grid.Style>




    <Image Source="E:\testImages\test.bmp" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a ViewBox. Like this:

```
<ViewBox>
  <Grid>
    <Image ..../>
  </Grid>
</ViewBox>
```

The ViewBox will automatically resize to the Image size, so the image will not be cropped.

Comment: It is not what I was asking about.